# angularJS 1.5 component that uses a factory: how to do it in typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, components, factory

the last two days i have been trying to re-write my js files into typescript. I have a simple app that works fine, and now im just learning typescript. So i have two js files in here. Could someone show me how to do this in typescript? I have gone through thousands of examples but most of them just use http in the component (instead of a factory). What im trying to achieve is to have two different files, one with the factory, and the other one with some component that actually uses that factory. These are the js files:

module.js:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

var module = angular.module("psShopping", ["ngComponentRouter"]);

module.value("$routerRootComponent", "shoppingApp");

module.factory('products', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return $http.get('/products.json')
           .success(function (data) {
               return data;
           })
           .error(function (data) {
               return data;
           });
}]);}());
```

shopping-list.component.js:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

var module = angular.module("psShopping");

function controller(products) {

    var model = this;
    model.products = [];

    model.$onInit = function () {
        products.success(function (data) {
            model.products = data;
        });
    };
}

module.component("shoppingList", {
    templateUrl: "shopping-list.component.html",
    controllerAs: "model",
    controller: ["products", controller],
    bindings: {
        "$router": "<"
    }

});}());
```

Please just focus on showing me how to do handle this in typescript. Im sure the code itself is fine because this is a part of an app that works perfectly fine. Im just learning typescript and I just have no idea how to go with this component since its using 'products' factory.